# Hide Google Doogle from Chrome "New Tab"?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, google-doodle

this might question might not belong here, but idk where a better place would be.
Is there a way to remove the Google Doodle from the "New Tab" page in Chrome?

It's often "Corona, stay safe" lately, and I spend a lot of time on the web, and find it quite depressing to be reminded of it all the time.

I tried AdBlock, but it doesn't want to block stuff on that page for me :/.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can't find a fix for the New Tab page. But you can control the startup page and home page (Alt + Home) by setting `about:blank` [^1] instead of "New Tab page" in chrome://settings/appearance and chrome://settings/onStartup. After that searches can simply be done with the address bar (Alt + d).

Also, Vimium users can simply type O (big o) to automatically open search results in the new page without needing to look at the New Tab page.

[^1]: `about:blank` alternatives can be found by going to `chrome://chrome-urls/` assuming that you don't want to use a URL that needs internet to load.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [Adblock](https://adblockplus.org/) extension, and make sure to block http://www.google.com/logos/*